# how to build rc transmitter and receiver with an old rc transmitter

Tags: arduino-mega, pwm, arduino-nano, wireless

I've got an Arduino Mega, an Arduino Nano, two NRF24L01 wireless modules and a old Multiplex Transmitter system.

I want to get the PWM signal and send it to the other arduino which should control the servos and the motor controller.

Is there a good instruction or know somebody how to do that easily?

I need it for a rc plane and the range should be 1km.

Comment: 1km is pretty much impossible with the NRF24L01

Comment: Do you know another wireless modules??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are controlling an RC plane, you should probably just buy a transmitter and receiver specifically designed for that. They are cheap and reliable and will generate PWM signals on their own.

If you must use an Arduino for some reason, NRF24L01 are not going to cut it as they are not powerful enough to reach 1 km. You should probably look into something like an XBee Series 1. With about 60 mW transmit power, its range is up to 1.6 km.